# Inserting to selected table name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a table called Aliases in my MySQL database.

Looks like this:

```
------------------
| Id    | Alias  |
------------------
|1      | 'TabX' |
------------------
|2      | 'TabY' |

...    

|       |        |
------------------
```

And I need to insert to those tables like this:

```
INSERT INTO (SELECT Alias FROM Aliases WHERE id=1) (somevalue) VALUES (value);
```

This doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: You have to build it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach it with prepared statements:

```
SET @alias = (SELECT Alias FROM Aliases WHERE id = 1);
SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', @alias, ' (somevalue) VALUES (value)');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Comment: Welcome any time, i'm glad that it's help you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `PROCEDURE` for that. And use prepared statements for this purpose. You need procedure like that:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `DB`.`INSERT_VAR`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`host` PROCEDURE INSERT_VAR(IN tableName VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
SET @insert_query=CONCAT("INSERT INTO ", tableName, " (id) SELECT id FROM test");
PREPARE stmtInsert FROM @insertTab;
EXECUTE stmtInsert;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You need to modify this procedure to fit your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT Alias 
  FROM Aliases 
 WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: OP wants to insert some rows into tables with variable names. In your example you use concrete constant name `table_name`.